# How can I intercept the push of the physical power button in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, power-management

Is there any way to intercept the event of the physical power button being pressed in order to react to this event? i.e.:

```
Push button -> My program catches the event -> My program performs action.
```

My goal is to write a C# program/service that will listen for the power button event and then open the "Ask me what to do" shutdown dialog (Like it did back in the days of Windows XP).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting windows shutdown event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173825/detecting-windows-shutdown-event)

Comment: @Jason: not a duplicate.  The OP is asking about intercepting the push of the power button (so that it does something other than shutting down) whereas the other question is about detecting that the system is shutting down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deny shutdown when pressing the power button for a while?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642058/how-to-deny-shutdown-when-pressing-the-power-button-for-a-while)

Comment: If it's not a duplicate of those two, then you have to do something like this: http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/189160-set-custom-option-power-button-action-list-default.html

Comment: I know that you can use CallNtPowerInformation with SystemPowerPolicyAc (and/or Dc) to disable the power button so that it does nothing; to do this you need to set `PowerButton.Action` to `PowerActionNone` and `PowerButton.EventCode` to `POWER_FORCE_TRIGGER_RESET`.  The same API provides an option for executing a program but it isn't clear to me how to use it.  You may be able to work it out by experimentation, or perhaps searching on the keyword `POWER_LEVEL_USER_NOTIFY_EXEC` will give you some clues.

Comment: @DaveShaw: I don't think that's a duplicate either; that question wants to know how to prevent the user from forcing a power-off by holding the power button down (as opposed to pressing it normally) which is of course impossible since that behaviour is built in at the hardware level.  What the OP wants here is at least physically possible, it just depends whether Windows allows it or not. :-)

Comment: @DaveShaw: The link you provided seems like it's referring to the software power button in the start menu.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I will investigate what you suggested. It seems you understand what I wish to do.

Comment: What do you mean "ask me what to do?" reality is collapsing for your app it should pray "Our father.." and check things retrospective when it comes back online.

Comment: This is the 'ask me what to do' dialog: [link](http://i.imgur.com/FIdwRxv.png)

Comment: [Capturing Physical Power Button Event](https://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=246968)

Answer (score 0):

You could use
[SystemEvents.SessionEnding Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx)

However I am not sure if this will work if the power button is pressed, this event Occurs when the user is trying to log off or shut down the system.

Answer (score 0):

I can explain it to you in theory: The button (it's a button that's tied to shutdown on most systems) has an option under "power options", where you can specificy the action to take when the power button is pressed...

It's that ACTION event you're looking for that's bound to the button by windows that THEN instantiates the shutdown event.  There's programs that dissect and monitor windows variables and calls, you'd have to use one of those to figure it out and intercept/override it.